# Generate 10 unique integers in C# for Unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I want to generate 10 'random' numbers, but they have to be unique. I have tried something, but is there someone who can help me out with something better?

My code:

```
List<int> ran = new List<int>();
Random rnd = new Random();
public static int randomValue;

int tempRandom;
public int randomNum()
{
    if(ran.Count == 0)
    {
        ran.Add(0);
        ran.Add(1);
        ran.Add(2);
        ran.Add(3);
        ran.Add(4);
        ran.Add(5);
        ran.Add(6);
        ran.Add(7);
    }
    tempRandom = rnd.Next(0, ran.Count);
    randomValue = ran[randomValue];
    ran.RemoveAt(tempRandom);

    return randomValue;
}
```

Comment: So you require 10 unique integers between 1 and 10?

Comment: This should help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt

Comment: 10 unique integral numbers between 1 and 10... I am thinking of 10 possible numbers...

Comment: This question isn't about randomness..

Comment: And who better than @RandomStranger to talk about randomness :)

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do about it. He's asking for a list of unique numbers.

Comment: @RandomStranger It was just a joke with your nick. Never mind :)

Comment: @RandomStranger if i can Add this 10 number to List or Generate 10 Unique Integers

Comment: there are plenty of ways. how do you mean better? and what is the purpose? please answer to these questions in your question.

Comment: You say you wish to "generate ten random numbers", but what you actually do is *shuffle the numbers from 0 to 7*.  There are far better ways to shuffle a list than what you're doing here, and the question of how to shuffle efficiently has been asked probably dozens of times.  I would delete this question and **do some research on efficient shuffle algorithms**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to say? If not, please specify how you mean further. This code should give you a number between 1-10 that hasn't been already used. This code will only work 10 times.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<int> usedNumbers = new List<int>();


public int RandomNum(){
    int number;
    do {
        number = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    } while(usedNumbers.IndexOf(number) == -1);

    usedNumbers.Add(number);

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight answer to your question (not regarding if you actually want what you are asking for):

```
Random.Range( int.MinValue, int.MaxValue );
```

This simply produces a random int in the range of all integers. For 10 numbers, the probability of duplicates is so little that every number will be unique.